# Search for matching binary values and delete those who got found

Tags: powershell, registry

Basically, what I am trying to do is this:
I try to do a Powershell script which searches a certain path of the registry:

Example:

`"HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU"`

In there, all the Bags are listed in REG_BINARY.
The goal I want to achieve is that I can define a path that is going to be searched for a specific value.

The value Im gonna use as a example is a USB drive letter, which will be the value "E:\". The value that I just defined will then be used to search in the also defined path.

The important part comes now: I don't want to search for names of a string, I want to search for the binary values of a string.

IMPORTANT: I don't want to predefine the string because in the path I mentioned above you don't know what bag is containing the value I want to search. The value I want to search can be in any bag, therefore the script should search in every string of the bags.

And here begins the problem I have right now:

I know how to search a string in the registry and delete it, that is no problem, but I don't know how to search for binary values. Let's say I got the path:

`"HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU"`

And there are 10 strings named from 1 to 10. I don't know where my specific binary value is located in which string. Therefore, I need to search the binary values for my specific value.

I didn't find anything helpful yet, so I try to find some help here :)

Comment: How is what you are asking any different than looking at a bunch of folders for files that have a specific string in them? You have to ```-recurse``` the hive to look get the value, to get the list of bags with the target value. ```Get-ChildItem -Path 'SomePath' -Recurse```, then stuff like ```Select-String```, or ```Where-Object``` or other RegEx matching. ```Get-ItemProperty``` and/or ```Get-ItemPropertyValue``` are also an options for this use case.  I am not sure where or what you looked for, but there are many examples (partial or otherwise) to get you to your end results.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment. You need to look at your use case in the discovery stages to see what you can/want to do. For example:

```
$RegistryPath = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU'

Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path  $RegistryPath
# Results
<#
...
Name                           Property
----                           --------
0                              NodeSlot  : 1
                               MRUListEx : {255, 255, 255, 255}
1                              0         : {58, 0, 46, 128, 146, 43, 22, 211,
...
#>


Clear-Host
Get-ItemProperty -Path  $RegistryPath -Name 1 | 
Get-Member
# Results
<#
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name         MemberType   Definition
----         ----------   ----------
Equals       Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method       type GetType()
ToString     Method       string ToString()
1            NoteProperty byte[] 1=System.Byte[]
PSChildName  NoteProperty string PSChildName=BagMRU
PSDrive      NoteProperty PSDriveInfo PSDrive=HKCU
PSParentPath NoteProperty string PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell...
PSPath       NoteProperty string PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\..
PSProvider   NoteProperty ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft...
#>


Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name 1
# Results
<#
1            : {20, 0, 31, 80, 224, 79, 208, 32, 234, 58, 105, 16, 162, 216, 8, 0, 43, 48, 48, 157, 0, 0}
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell
PSChildName  : BagMRU
PSDrive      : HKCU
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
#>


Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path  $RegistryPath -Recurse -Force | 
Where-Object {$PSItem.Property -eq 10}
# Results
<#
    Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU


Name                           Property                                                                                                                                  
----                           --------                                                                                                                                  
1                              0         : {58, 0, 46, 128, 146, 43, 22, 211...                       


    Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU\1


Name                           Property                                                                                                                                  
----                           --------                                                                                                                                  
1                              NodeSlot  : 3                                                                                                                             
                               MRUListEx : {21, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0,...                                             
11                             NodeSlot  : 100                                                                                                                           
                               MRUListEx : {13, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0,...                                  


    Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU\1\13\1\4


Name                           Property                                                                                                                                  
----                           --------                                                                                                                                  
4                              NodeSlot  : 529                                                                                                                           
                               MRUListEx : {13, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, ...

...
#>



Clear-Host 
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $RegistryPath -Name 1
# Results
<#
20
0
...
#>
    
Clear-Host
ForEach (
    $BagRecord in (
                      Get-ChildItem -Path  $RegistryPath -Recurse -Force | 
                      Select-Object -First 3
                  )
)
{
    Write-Host "`nChecking value for BagName $($BagRecord.PSChildName)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    (Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $RegistryPath -Name ($BagRecord.PSChildName)) -join ','
}
# Results
<#
Checking value for BagName 0
20,0,31,128,203,133,159,103...

Checking value for BagName 1
20,0,31,80,224,79,208,32,23...

Checking value for BagName 0
20,0,31,128,203,133,159,103,...
#>
```

Once you have the above then, replace, or do what you will.

Others may have more elegant ways to provide you, but the above is Q&D (quick and dirty) ways to dig at this.